# Data cardinality is ambiguous, Model.fit Issue with Functional API

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I have multiple inputs for one output through using the functional API.

```
My first input shape is X1 = (34105, 100, 1).
My second input shape is X2 = (17,100).
My output Y = (34105, 27)
```

The function is:

```
model.fit([X1,X2], Y, epochs = 2, batch_size=128)
```

The error is as follows:

Data cardinality is ambiguous:
x sizes: 34105, 17
y sizes: 34105
Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples.

Comment: Why is your second input only 17 samples?

Comment: I am doing an Experiment, so its only 17 samples for this dataset

Comment: Well you cannot use datasets like that if they have different number of samples

Comment: So how about if I can do the padding would that work ?

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about, you would be generating synthetic samples which biases the model.

Comment: Well, I am confused too would you like to take a look over my code? so we can discuss that am doing, I am sure you will help me to find a proper solution

Comment: No, there is no proper solution, you cannot combine unrelated datasets and expect things to work properly. There is literally no relationship between samples, wwhich is required for this kinn of model.

Comment: you are right! well, what I am trying to do is combine the LDA model which is a topic model with the LSTM model to enhance the auto-complete texting, So the 17 samples are the keywords related to the article that I am trying to train the model over it. So I have no idea to tell the model here's the topic and here's the article work on it!

Comment: Dr.Snoopy May, I have your email, Next year I will have a thesis, so I need a good ideas to start looking for, if would like to help

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience with this but my friend says
convert your list of numpy 3D arrays to a one 4D array. You can use np.stack for that

Comment: For each input? but the model only takes 3 dimensional array, 
(None, 34105) <dtype: 'float32'>
(None, 17) <dtype: 'float32'>
(None, 27) <dtype: 'float32'>